# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation does not exist with recursive model

Tags: python, django, heroku, psycopg2

I have a django app that is working as intended on my local pc. but when I'm deploying it to heroku it prints the message:

> django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "core_menuoption" does not exist

Now, I searched about this a lot, but no case is similar as mine. I think that my problem is because my model `MenuOption` is recuesive. Here is the model:

```
class MenuOption(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    
    ...
```

As you can see, the parameter `parent` is a foreign key to this model. So I think becuase the model is not yet created,  django doesn't know which model to relate to.

I thought about maybe deleting this field, migrate and than bring it back, but too many things rely on this field.

Full traceback:

```
remote: Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
remote:     return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
remote: psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "core_menuoption" does not exist
remote: LINE 1: ...tion"."parent_id", "core_menuoption"."title" FROM "core_menu...
remote:                                                              ^
remote:
remote:
remote: The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
remote:
remote: Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:   File "/app/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
remote:     main()
remote:   File "/app/manage.py", line 18, in main
remote:     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
remote:     utility.execute()
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
remote:     self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
remote:     self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
remote:     output = self.handle(*args, **options)
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 89, in wrapped
remote:     res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 75, in handle
remote:     self.check(databases=[database])
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 419, in check
remote:     all_issues = checks.run_checks(
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 76, in run_checks
remote:     new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 40, in check_url_namespaces_unique
remote:     all_namespaces = _load_all_namespaces(resolver)
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 57, in _load_all_namespaces
remote:     url_patterns = getattr(resolver, 'url_patterns', [])
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
remote:     res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 598, in url_patterns
remote:     patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
remote:     res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 591, in urlconf_module
remote:     return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
remote:     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
remote:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
remote:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
remote:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
remote:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
remote:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 855, in exec_module
remote:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
remote:   File "/app/ExplosiveArea/urls.py", line 20, in <module>
remote:     path('', include('core.urls')),
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
remote:     urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
remote:     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
remote:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
remote:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
remote:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
remote:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
remote:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 855, in exec_module
remote:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
remote:   File "/app/core/urls.py", line 3, in <module>
remote:     from . import views
remote:   File "/app/core/views.py", line 11, in <module>
remote:     from core.forms import UserForm, MenuOptionForm, ExerciseForm
remote:   File "/app/core/forms.py", line 20, in <module>
remote:     class MenuOptionForm(forms.ModelForm):
remote:   File "/app/core/forms.py", line 21, in MenuOptionForm
remote:     class Meta:
remote:   File "/app/core/forms.py", line 25, in Meta
remote:     'parent': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control mb-1'}, choices=[(m, m) for m in MenuOption.objects.all()]),
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 280, in __iter__
remote:     self._fetch_all()
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1324, in _fetch_all
remote:     self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 51, in __iter__
remote:     results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1175, in execute_sql
remote:     cursor.execute(sql, params)
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
remote:     return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
remote:     return executor(sql, params, many, context)
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
remote:     return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
remote:     raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
remote:     return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
remote: django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "core_menuoption" does not exist
remote: LINE 1: ...tion"."parent_id", "core_menuoption"."title" FROM "core_menu...
```

MenuOptionForm class:

```
class MenuOptionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MenuOption
        fields = ('parent', 'title')
        widgets = {
            'parent': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control mb-1'}, choices=[(m, m) for m in MenuOption.objects.all()]),
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'title})
        }
```

Comment: Well did you run `migrate` _on heroku_? and are your migrations added to your version control?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Yes, I did `migrate` on heroku. What do you mean by adding my migrations to version control? I've uploaded django projects to heroku before and never did anything with the migrations except running them.

Comment: How did you do it? [edit] your question. Also add the _full_ error traceback to the question. By adding the migrations to version control I mean that your migration files should be commited to your git repository.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Yes, it is in the version control. I added a full traceback.

Comment: Show the class `MenuOptionForm` in `core/forms.py`

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I've just appended it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your migrations never got applied, you in fact should have gotten this same error when you ran `migrate` on the server. The issue here is you have the following line:

```
'parent': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control mb-1'}, choices=[(m, m) for m in MenuOption.objects.all()]),
```

This line naturally makes a query to the database, well what's wrong with that? This line is executed at the time the class `MenuOptionForm` is made, which happens even before `migrate` (hence the error, the migration has not even happened yet) actually gets run since all your files are imported before that. Another issue with this is that your options in this form will **never** change unless you reload the server, which is likely not what you intend to happen.

What you need to do is **not** pass the choices here, Since you haven't specified the form field manually the field used here is a `ModelChoiceField` which will take care of setting the choices by itself:

```
class MenuOptionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MenuOption
        fields = ('parent', 'title')
        widgets = {
            'parent': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control mb-1'}),
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'title})
        }
```

Now we need to migrate the changes to the database, first make sure your migrations are commited to your repository and the commit is pushed to heroku. Next if you are using the Heroku CLI then you can simply run:

```
heroku run python manage.py migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @AbdulAzizBarkat, I figured out the problem was in the MenuOptionForm class. I tried to append all objects of MenuOption class to the choices, but the class was unmigrated.
So I changed the choices list to something like:

```
...
'parent': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control mb-1'}, choices=["1","2","3"]),
...
```

Than heroku could create the tables for me and than I changed it back and everything worked fine!

Comment: **Don't** specify the choices in the widget, the `ModelChoiceField` will take care of that itself. See my answer above.