# How to do migrations in your old models?

Tags: python, django

I created 2 models:

```
from django.db import models

class Company(models.Model):

     name = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Puzzle(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    number_of_pieces = models.IntegerField()
    ean_code = models.CharField(max_length=13, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='puzzles')
    product_code = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True, null=True)
    website = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

And I added some sample models. Now I want to change model Company add new field for example:

```
class Company(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=False)
```

When I do: py manage.py makemigrations I have error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\code\Django\FanPuzzle\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "E:\code\Django\FanPuzzle\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 477, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: puzzle_company.description

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File ".\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "E:\code\Django\FanPuzzle\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "E:\code\Django\FanPuzzle\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line .
.
.
  File "E:\code\Django\FanPuzzle\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "E:\code\Django\FanPuzzle\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 477, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column: puzzle_company.description
```

What do I do wrong?
Here is my whole project: https://github.com/MatRos-sf/Django-FanPuzzle

Comment: This link can be helpful [stackoverflow/sqlite3operationalerror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21142531/sqlite3-operationalerror-no-such-column)

Comment: Such problems are usually due to a query being run before any view is run. I had a quick look at your repo, in your `AddPuzzleForm` you have the line `COMPANIES = [(i.id, i) for i in Company.objects.all()]` which is the problem. Have you see [ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) you should never make a choice field like that by querying the DB (It would not update the choices when something new is added unless you restart the server)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation does not exist with recursive model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68314549/django-db-utils-programmingerror-relation-does-not-exist-with-recursive-model)